# Почему не срабатывает MySQL запрос?

Tags: mysqli, mysql

Делаю такой запрос в MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO
  lidvj_categories (title, alias, parent_id, published, access, extension)
SELECT
  name, alias, parent, published, access, 'com_content'
FROM
  lidvj_k2_categories
```

Он выдает нулевой результат:

```
MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). (Запрос занял 0.0530 сек.)
```

Но если я выполняю просто запрос SELECT:

```
SELECT name, alias, parent, published, access, 'com_content' FROM lidvj_k2_categories
```

Выдает нормальную таблицу - `Отображение строк 0 - 30 (31 всего, Запрос занял 0.0010 сек.)`

Comment: А записи в таблице lidvj_categories появились?

Comment: точка с запятой для разделения команд, error reporting для выдачи ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Запрос `SELECT` предназначен для извлечения данных из одной или нескольких таблиц. Однако, запрос `INSERT ... SELECT ...` выполняет другую функцию, он вставляет данные из `SELECT` запроса в таблицу. Поэтому этот запрос возвращает

```
MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).
```

Задача этого запроса не извлечение, а вставка данных.